# How to interpret line break between two MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, line-breaks, nl2br

I've an old MySQL database with this column: **note** encoded as ut8_general_ci, type longtext

I've a new MySQL database with this column: **publicNote**  encoded as ut8_general_ci, type longtext

So, i would like to migrate the data from the old database to the new one.
To do this, i've PHP script to request my old database and to do some processing on the data. I've a problem here.

There is an exemple of the old database data

```
De : XXXX 
Vers : Gare
Vol/Train : TGV Paris
Heure : XXXX


Destination : XXXX
```

There are two line break between 'Heure' and 'Destination' lines.

And the data migrated to the new database :

```
De : XXXXX Vers : Gare Vol/Train : TGV Paris Heure : XXXX Destination : XXXX
```

As you can see, the line break are not added to the new database. I've tried to do nl2br, str_replace, trim but it doesn't work.
If we look at the hexa code, i can not seen backspace code, just space (code 20).

```
bin2hex($row['publicNote'])
4465203a20585858582056657273203a204761726520566f6c2f547261696e203a20544756205061726973204865757265203a20585858582044657374696e6174696f6e203a2058585858
```

If we look at the json_encode($row['publicNote']):

```
De : XXXX Vers : Gare Vol\/Train : TGV Paris Heure : XXXX Destination : XXXX
```

I'm really confused, i do not understand why the line break are not interpreted.
It's like if there are not \n to the end of the line on mysql

Comment: put your php tries here, and only for curiosity why you simply don't copy your database then change your columns names ?

Comment: I can not copy paste data between the two databases. I'm developping new version of my website and the databases are not the sames. I've to do it the php script.

I've tried :

    $newDatabase['publicNote'] = nl2br($row['note']);
    $newDatabase['publicNote'] = trim($row['note']);
    $newDatabase['publicNote'] = str-replace("\n", "<br />", $row['note']);

Comment: shouldn't these things be separate fields, not just one big string? If you're changing your database design, here's a good opportunity to normalise it

Comment: No i can not sorry. This field contains comment.

Comment: I added json_encore and bin2hex result

Comment: what mysql library are you using `mysql`, `mysqli`, or `PDO`?

Comment: I'm under Symfony with Doctrine.